# r + tfidf and inverse document frequency

Tags: r, nlp

I was hoping that someone can explain a specific part of an academic paper and assist in writing R code for that section:

**Name of Paper**

- Large-scale Analysis of Counseling Conversations:
  An Application of Natural Language Processing to Mental Health (https://cs.stanford.edu/people/jure/pubs/counseling-tacl16.pdf)

On page 5, we have the following snippet:

"
...build a TF-IDF vector of word occurrences
to represent the language of counselors within this
subset. We use the global inverse document (i.e.,
conversation) frequencies instead of the ones from
each subset to make the vectors directly comparable
and control for different counselors having different numbers of conversations by weighting conversations so all counselors have equal contributions.
"

What does the paper mean by "global inverse document frequency"?
How can I code this in R with the different subsets (positive and negative counsellors for example)

Here is my sample code:

```
corp_pos_1 <- Corpus(VectorSource(positive_chats$Text1))
#corp_pos_1  <- tm_map(corp_pos_1, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

tdm_pos_1 <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp_pos_1,control = list(weighting = function(x) weightTfIdf(x, normalize = FALSE)))
ui = unique(tdm_pos_1 $i)
tdm_pos_1  = tdm_pos_1 [ui,]

cosine_tdm_pos_1 <- crossprod_simple_triplet_matrix(tdm_pos_1)/(sqrt(col_sums(tdm_pos_1^2) %*% t(col_sums(tdm_pos_1^2))))
```

In the code 'pos' stands for positive, and 'neg' would stand for negative. 
The number at the end of the variable end shows the part of the chunk being calculated.

Now I have them chunked in 5 different parts trying to follow this paper. But how would I be able to calculate "global inverse document frequency"?

I think I have found this stackoverflow question from before but I am still not understanding the paper + what I need to do in R.
[R: weighted inverse document frequency (tfidf) similarity between strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56365000/r-weighted-inverse-document-frequency-tfidf-similarity-between-strings)

Answer (score 0):

TF/IDF is a well-known measure in information retrieval. For more information on it, and formulae that describe how to calculate it, see the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).

In short, you want to have words that are specific to texts; words that occur in all texts do not add any distinctive information. So, the *inverse* document frequency is the number of all documents divided by the number of documents that contain a given word. For common words such as *the* or *of*, the IDF would be 1.0, as we would assume they occurred in all texts. For that reason they are often excluded as stop words. IDF can also be scaled, eg by taking the logarithm.

If I understand your application correctly, you would take a term and divide the total number of documents by the number of negative documents that contain the term.